# How to align text in custom radio type inputs Sweetalert

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I'm using sweetalert for the choices of declaration decisions. In the text section I'm using input classes with radio type.
Can I align checkboxes with text to the left? Probably this is div 'p'.

I tried many options but it still does not work :(

Can you help me?

```
swal({
    type: "info",
    title: "Reasons:",
    text:
      "<input class=\"visibleInput\" align=\"left\" type=\"radio\" name=\"reason\" id=\"E1\" value=\"FV1\"> FV1text<br>" +
      "<input class=\"visibleInput\" align=\"left\" type=\"radio\" name=\"reason\" id=\"EOther\" value=\"FV2\"> FV2text<br>",
    textAlign: "left",
    showCancelButton: false,
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false,
    confirmButtonText: "Confirm",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancel",
    html: true
  },
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) - the supported fork of original SweetAlert:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Select color',
  input: 'radio',
  customClass: {
    input: 'my-radio'
  },
  inputOptions: {
    '#ff0000': 'Red',
    '#00ff00': 'Green',
    '#0000ff': 'Blue'
  }
})
```

```css
.my-radio {
  display: inline-flex !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
```

PS. notice that SweetAlert2 is a little bit different from SweetAlert, check the simple migration guide: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/wiki/Migration-from-SweetAlert-to-SweetAlert2